# How to convert a pytorch tensor of ints to a tensor of booleans?

Tags: python, casting, boolean, pytorch, tensor

I would like to cast a tensor of ints to a tensor of booleans.

Specifically I would like to be able to have a function which transforms `tensor([0,10,0,16])` to `tensor([0,1,0,1])`

This is trivial in Tensorflow by just using `tf.cast(x,tf.bool)`.

I want the cast to change all ints greater than 0 to a 1 and all ints equal to 0 to a 0. This is the equivalent of `!!` in most languages.

Since pytorch does not seem to have a dedicated boolean type to cast to, what is the best approach here?

Edit: I am looking for a vectorized solution opposed to looping through each element.

Comment: Call   `bool(int)` on  each element. Or in numpy: Use `array.astype(...)`

Comment: That is the trivial solution which requires a for-loop, yes. But is there a vectorized solution?

Comment: The `astype` version is almost surely vectorized.

Comment: @ThomasLang there is no `.astype` in pytorch, so one would have to `convert to numpy-> cast -> load to pytorch` which IMO is inefficient

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What you're looking for is to generate a **boolean mask** for the given integer tensor. For this, you can simply check for the condition: "whether the values in the tensor are greater than 0" using simple comparison operator (`>`) or using [**`torch.gt()`**](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.gt.html), which would then give us the desired result.

```
# input tensor
In [76]: t   
Out[76]: tensor([ 0, 10,  0, 16])

# generate the needed boolean mask
In [78]: t > 0      
Out[78]: tensor([0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

---

```
# sanity check
In [93]: mask = t > 0      

In [94]: mask.type()      
Out[94]: 'torch.ByteTensor'
```

---

**Note**: In PyTorch version 1.4+, the above operation would return `'torch.BoolTensor'`

```
In [9]: t > 0  
Out[9]: tensor([False,  True, False,  True])

# alternatively, use `torch.gt()` API
In [11]: torch.gt(t, 0)
Out[11]: tensor([False,  True, False,  True])
```

If you indeed want single bits (either `0`s or `1`s), cast it using:

```
In [14]: (t > 0).type(torch.uint8)   
Out[14]: tensor([0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=torch.uint8)

# alternatively, use `torch.gt()` API
In [15]: torch.gt(t, 0).int()
Out[15]: tensor([0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=torch.int32)
```

The reason for this change has been discussed in this feature-request issue: [issues/4764 - Introduce torch.BoolTensor ...](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4764)

---

**TL;DR**: Simple one liner

```
t.bool().int()
```

Comment: This returns 'torch.BoolTensor' in PyTorch 1.4.0.

Answer (score 6):

PyTorch's `to(dtype)` method has convenient [data-type named aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66536932/9067615). You can simply call `bool`:

```py
>>> t.bool()
tensor([False,  True, False,  True])
```

```py
>>> t.bool().int()
tensor([0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=torch.int32)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use comparisons as shown below:

```
 >>> a = tensor([0,10,0,16])
 >>> result = (a == 0)
 >>> result
 tensor([ True, False,  True, False])
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Convert boolean to number value:**
>
> ```
> a = torch.tensor([0,4,0,0,5,0.12,0.34,0,0])
> print(a.gt(0)) # output in boolean dtype
> # output: tensor([False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False])
>
> print(a.gt(0).to(torch.float32)) # output in float32 dtype
> # output: tensor([0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.])
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to simply do:

```
temp = torch.tensor([0,10,0,16])
temp.bool()
#Returns
tensor([False,  True, False,  True])
```