# Why would we use to() method in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I've seen this method multiple times. What are the purposes and advantages of doing this?

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to)? If so, what is exactly your question?

Comment: Quick Add on...
Under the hood, `type` and `to` methods perform the same type check & convert if needed, but the `to` method can take additional arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why would we use to(device) method in pytorch?

[`torch.Tensor.to`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to) is multipurpose method.

Not only you can do type conversion, but it can also do CPU to GPU tensor move and GPU to CPU tensor move:

```
tensor = torch.randn(2, 2)  
print(tensor)
tensor = tensor.to(torch.float64) 
print(tensor) #dtype=torch.float64
tensor = tensor.to("cuda") 
print(tensor) #device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64)
tensor = tensor.to("cpu") 
print(tensor) #dtype=torch.float64
tensor = tensor.to(torch.float32) 
print(tensor) # won't print dtype=torch.float32 since it is by default
```

Since CPU and GPU are different kind memories, there must be a way they communicate.
This is why we have `to("cuda")`, and `to("cpu")` that we call on tensor.

Usually when you load training datasets (images):

- you download them from URL (like MNIST http://deeplearning.net/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz)
- unpack them
- convert them to numpy arrays
- convert numpy arrays to tensors (as this is fast)
- move them to GPU for training .`to("cuda")`

You can create tensors and move them to GPU like this.

```
torch.zeros(1000).to("cuda")
```

But there is a trick, sometimes you can even load them directly to GPU without messing the CPU.

```
torch.zeros(1000, device="gpu")
```

Comment: This was very helpful. How come you first convert the unpacked data to numpy arrays and then to tensors? Why not convert directly to tensors? I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50308132/6942666) where you could convert a Pandas DF straight to a tensor, so not sure why you couldn't always go straight to a tensor.

Comment: "convert numpy arrays to tensors (as this is fast)", other approaches may be slower.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! @prosti

Comment: sometimes, there is another  `to` function usage case, i.e., `tensor.view(a,b,c).to(another_tensor)`, in this case, the `to() `function is to keep the type of output as `another_tensor`

Answer (score 2):

#### [`.to(device)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62907815/pytorch-what-is-the-difference-between-using-tensor-cuda-and-tensor-totorch)

`.to()` can be used to copy a tensor to any available device (CPU, GPU):

```py
x = torch.randn(3)

x_g0 = x.to('cuda:0')
x_c = x.to('cpu')
```

It has aliases `.cuda()` and `.cpu()`.

---

#### [`.to(dtype)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to)

When given a dtype as an arument `.to()` acts as a casting method:

```py
x_d = x.to(torch.double)
```

It has dtype-named aliases `.double()`, `.float()`, `.int()` etc

Answer (score 0):

@prosti and @iacob's answer is good. Here I just want to show you the source code of `to()` function of `pytorch.to()`

sometimes, there is another  `to` function usage case, i.e., `tensor.view(a,b,c).to(another_tensor)`, in this case, the `to()` function is to keep the type of output as `another_tensor`

This case is the last usage example in the following code.

```
>>> other = torch.randn((), dtype=torch.float64, device=cuda0)
>>> tensor.to(other, non_blocking=True)
tensor([[-0.5044,  0.0005],
       [ 0.3310, -0.0584]], dtype=torch.float64, device='cuda:0')
```

The following is the whole source code about `torch.to()` function.

```
  def to(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """
    to(*args, **kwargs) -> Tensor
    
    Performs Tensor dtype and/or device conversion. A :class:`torch.dtype` and :class:`torch.device` are
    inferred from the arguments of ``self.to(*args, **kwargs)``.
    
    .. note::
    
        If the ``self`` Tensor already
        has the correct :class:`torch.dtype` and :class:`torch.device`, then ``self`` is returned.
        Otherwise, the returned tensor is a copy of ``self`` with the desired
        :class:`torch.dtype` and :class:`torch.device`.
    
    Here are the ways to call ``to``:
    
    .. method:: to(dtype, non_blocking=False, copy=False, memory_format=torch.preserve_format) -> Tensor
       :noindex:
    
        Returns a Tensor with the specified :attr:`dtype`
    
        Args:
            memory_format (:class:`torch.memory_format`, optional): the desired memory format of
            returned Tensor. Default: ``torch.preserve_format``.
    
    .. method:: to(device=None, dtype=None, non_blocking=False, copy=False, memory_format=torch.preserve_format) -> Tensor
       :noindex:
    
        Returns a Tensor with the specified :attr:`device` and (optional)
        :attr:`dtype`. If :attr:`dtype` is ``None`` it is inferred to be ``self.dtype``.
        When :attr:`non_blocking`, tries to convert asynchronously with respect to
        the host if possible, e.g., converting a CPU Tensor with pinned memory to a
        CUDA Tensor.
        When :attr:`copy` is set, a new Tensor is created even when the Tensor
        already matches the desired conversion.
    
        Args:
            memory_format (:class:`torch.memory_format`, optional): the desired memory format of
            returned Tensor. Default: ``torch.preserve_format``.
    
    .. method:: to(other, non_blocking=False, copy=False) -> Tensor
       :noindex:
    
        Returns a Tensor with same :class:`torch.dtype` and :class:`torch.device` as
        the Tensor :attr:`other`. When :attr:`non_blocking`, tries to convert
        asynchronously with respect to the host if possible, e.g., converting a CPU
        Tensor with pinned memory to a CUDA Tensor.
        When :attr:`copy` is set, a new Tensor is created even when the Tensor
        already matches the desired conversion.
    
    Example::
    
        >>> tensor = torch.randn(2, 2)  # Initially dtype=float32, device=cpu
        >>> tensor.to(torch.float64)
        tensor([[-0.5044,  0.0005],
                [ 0.3310, -0.0584]], dtype=torch.float64)
    
        >>> cuda0 = torch.device('cuda:0')
        >>> tensor.to(cuda0)
        tensor([[-0.5044,  0.0005],
                [ 0.3310, -0.0584]], device='cuda:0')
    
        >>> tensor.to(cuda0, dtype=torch.float64)
        tensor([[-0.5044,  0.0005],
                [ 0.3310, -0.0584]], dtype=torch.float64, device='cuda:0')
    
        >>> other = torch.randn((), dtype=torch.float64, device=cuda0)
        >>> tensor.to(other, non_blocking=True)
        tensor([[-0.5044,  0.0005],
                [ 0.3310, -0.0584]], dtype=torch.float64, device='cuda:0')
    """
    return _te.Tensor(*(), **{})
```