# PyTorch: What is the difference between tensor.cuda() and tensor.to(torch.device("cuda:0"))?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

In PyTorch, what is the difference between the following two methods in sending a tensor (or model) to GPU:

Setup:

```
X = np.array([[1, 3, 2, 3], [2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4]]) # X = model()
X = torch.DoubleTensor(X)
```

| Method 1 | Method 2 |
| --- | --- |
| `X.cuda()` | `device = torch.device("cuda:0")` `X = X.to(device)` |

---

(I don't really need a detailed explanation of what is happening in the backend, just want to know if they are both essentially doing the same thing)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no difference between the two.
Early versions of pytorch had `.cuda()` and `.cpu()` methods to move tensors and models from cpu to gpu and back. However, this made code writing a bit cumbersome:

```py
if cuda_available:
  x = x.cuda()
  model.cuda()
else:
  x = x.cpu()
  model.cpu()
```

Later versions introduced `.to()` that basically takes care of everything in an elegant way:

```py
device = torch.device('cuda') if cuda_available else torch.device('cpu')
x = x.to(device)
model = model.to(device)
```

Answer (score 9):

Their syntax varies slightly, but [they are equivalent](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-using-tensor-cuda-and-tensor-to-torch-device-cuda-0/89259):

| ⠀ | .to(name) | .to(device) | .cuda() |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **CPU** | `to('cpu')` | `to(torch.device('cpu'))` | `cpu()` |
| **Current GPU** | `to('cuda')` | `to(torch.device('cuda'))` | `cuda()` |
| **Specific GPU** | `to('cuda:1')` | `to(torch.device('cuda:1'))` | `cuda(device=1)` |

Note: the current cuda device is `0` by default, but this can be set with `torch.cuda.set_device()`.